# Rails Migration Successful, But Not Showing up in Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I can't figure out why my migration worked but doesn't show up in corresponding model...

1. Ran a migration to add field to a table:

   ```
   def up
     add_column :quick_tests, :trace_route_data, :text, :null => true
   end

   def down
     remove_column :quick_tests, :trace_route_data
   end
   ```
2. Looked in `schema.rb`, and it's there.
3. Added `:trace_route_data` to `attr_accessible` in `QuickTest` model
4. Opened up rails console by doing `bundle exec rails c`, ran `QuickTest.new` and I can see the `:trace_route_data` field.

But, when I execute the same `QuickTest.new` statement when paused in the `QuickTestController#show` method, the field isn't there.

Why is this field showing up in the rails console but not my actual app??

Comment: have you added `trace_route_data` as `attr_accessible` in `quick_test.rb` model?

Comment: yes, I have. Added to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect something went wrong during the migration such that it never got applied to the database.  Rails uses the actual schema in the database to build model objects, so the fact that your model doesn't show the change means the change is almost certainly not in the database (despite being in the `schema.rb`).

I'd recommend you rollback your migration and run it again in verbose mode.  This should either show you the error, or at least show you the SQL being run.  In that case, you can run the SQL manually at the db console and see what happens then.

Comment: Ah! With your help I figured it out. I checked the database and saw the migration wasn't being applied. Turns out the migration was being applied to the local PG database and not the remote on the app was using...

Comment: I have the opposite issue - my new column, created through a migration, shows up when I enter the Model name in the console i.e. -> User.take -> :id, :new_column - but it doesn't show up in the schema. Can I just pencil it in?

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland Probably, but the safest would be to rollback the change and re-apply. This will force Rails to regenerate the schema.rb.

Comment: Sometimes the development environment simply does not acknowledge a certain migration until you restart the rails-server itself. Just experienced the issue myself, having tried migration rollback first.